# How can I format my data in qgridlayout or similar widgets?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, pyqt4

```
def view(self):
    sender=self.sender()
    self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text()+' was pressed.')
    with sqlite3.connect('drycleaning_shop.db') as db:
        cursor=db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select* from Item Order BY Name ASC')
        product=cursor.fetchall()
        product=str(product)
        print(len(product))
        self.l.setText(str(product))
        self.l124.setText(view2)
```

This is what is representing my data at the moment, the data is printed into a label (l124) and is printed through a single line. I want the qgrid to have my data represented in a table of some sort organised in rows and columns.